# RecycleView with cards aligned in grid mode and others in list mode

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I want to create a RecycleView with 4 CardViews aligned in grid mode and the last one in list mode, is that possible? Do I need to customized LayoutManager?

Comment: By your description it looks like the layout will always have 5 elements. Just make static UI without using a recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`SpanSizeLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html) on your `GridLayoutManager`:

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 4 ? 2 : 1;
    }
});
```